# Why does this innovative method of subtraction from a third grader always work?

Tags: arithmetic

My daughter is in year $3$ and she is now working on subtraction up to $1000.$ She came up with a way of solving her simple sums that we (her parents) and her teachers can't understand.

Here is an example: $61-17$

Instead of borrowing, making it $50+11-17,$ and then doing what she was told in school $11-7=4,$ $50-10=40 \Longrightarrow 40+4=44,$ she does the following:

Units of the subtrahend minus units of the minuend $=7-1=6$
Then tens of the minuend minus tens of the subtrahend $=60-10=50$
Finally she subtracts the first result from the second $=50-6=44$

As it is against the first rule children learn in school regarding subtraction (subtrahend minus minuend, as they cannot invert the numbers in subtraction as they can in addition), how is it possible that this method always works? I have a medical background and am baffled with this…

Could someone explain it to me please? Her teachers are not keen on accepting this way when it comes to marking her exams.

Comment: You could think of borrowing the $6$ to be paid back later.  $61-17=(67-17)-6$.

Comment: @DavidQuinn yes, probably (see my answer for an interpretation of her method), and that's why she didn't do 10-60...

Comment: @Alice Not only should you let her do it this way; you should congratulate her for finding a creative solution and encourage her to continue doing so in the future despite what her teachers are saying; after all that lies at the heart of mathematics. Unfortunately, the school system usually suppresses any kind of creative mathematical thinking. I highly recommend Paul Lockhart's small book "A Mathematician's Lament" on this matter. You can find some part of it for free [here](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf).

Comment: Thanks to everyone! I will definitely have a look at the book, posilon.

Comment: This is how I subtract about half the time. The other half the time I subtract by adding progressively to the smaller number until it equals the larger and then adding up all the things I added to get the difference. Creative independent and technically correct and adept thinking is what your daughter has shown. I was in my 20s before I developed the technique she uses.

Comment: For the record, this is almost how I subtract.  I'd think "61-17, 1-7 can bring it down to a 6, and if I subtract that from a borrowed 10, I get 4 in the one's place.  6-1 is 5, -1 I borrowed brings it to 4."  Of course I don't step through all those words, but it's the same principle.  I suspect I "discovered"/started using it around elementary school, too, and it's never brought me trouble in math (which I've done extensively).

Comment: I wonder if she's also figured out that the easy way to add 9 to a number is to add 1 to the 10's digit and subtract 1 from the units. Discovering these shortcuts is a sign of good mathematical intuition, she recognizes the underlying processes and the patterns that result.

Comment: Who or what is a third grader? I can't even look up your schooling system to work it out, as you've neglected to mention which country you live in. Why not just give us an age? It's simpler.

Comment: How nice to get a question that's so different from the usual ones we get. Thank you for posting, and I agree that your daughter is very clever.

Comment: @TRiG: From the wording and content of the question, the OP is almost certainly in the U.S., where "third grade" typically means ages 8 to 9. When and where I was in school, you begin first grade (in late August) if your 6th birthday was between the previous Oct. 15 and the upcoming Oct. 15. This varies a little with "when" (for me, we're talking about 1965) and "where" (which state one lives in), but even allowing for this variation, someone in the first grade in February (the current month) would be 6 to 7 years old, and hence someone in the third grade in February would be 8 to 9 years old.

Comment: For those interested, typical U.S. third grade mathematics content can be seen [here](https://www.education.com/worksheets/third-grade/math/) and [here](http://www.k5learning.com/free-math-worksheets/third-grade-3) and [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-third-grade-math).

Comment: I have a computer science background and find the (presumably American) textbook way hard to understand and follow.

Comment: @Alice My comment probably isn't adding much... but I had a few similar experiences with teachers growing up. Thankfully a couple had math backgrounds and helped prove my methods correct. mathematical inventiveness is a wonderfully useful thing later in life, don't let the teachers snuff it out. :-)

Comment: @Dave. Thanks, that gives some helpful context, but still, that info should be added to the question. (Alice, I suggest you do that.)

Comment: I'd be interested to know how she does if the minuend is more than the subtuend, e.g. 67 - 11, so 1 - 7= -6.

Comment: She is really amazing at this age. Don't stop her to use her own way. There is always more than one way to do a work and it is not wrong to take the way, the others are even not able to think.

Comment: Well, marking the exams in this case is tricky. Do the teachers want that she learns a method, or do they just care about the result? I agree that this is clever (especially because I did the same at that age :-P ), but if someone is teaching something and she learns something different, I understand the difficulty in giving a grade.

Comment: "Her teachers are not keen on accepting this way" -- now explain to them why the method works, and don't let them discourage your daughter from thinking outside the box. she's clearly brilliant and the last thing you want is the system getting in her way.

Comment: Where does the 50 come from? I mean, yes, $61=50+11$, but splitting the number in this way as a first step does not resemble any schoolbook subtraction algorithm that I would recognize. Is this some US thing?

Comment: Where I learned my math there is none of that "borrowing" nonsense. That gets taught later in economics classes. Your daughter is obviously smarter not only than her teachers, but also smarter than those who write the "methods" and the politicians who have the schools adopt them!

Comment: Have you considered asking your daughter to explain? Communicating math is really difficult, so it's hard to know if she'll be able to, but at least it seems like a great opportunity to practice.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Presumably because you borrow from the tens digit so you don't go below zero on the ones digit: 1-7 is negative, so we borrow 10 and reduce the 6 to a 5.

Comment: You (and your daughter) might enjoy exploding dots. Here's the subtraction lesson: http://gdaymath.com/lessons/explodingdots/4-1-welcome/

Comment: What this indicates to me is a keen sense of place value and distributivity. I hope your daughter won't let her teachers get in the way of doing math.

Comment: @Alice The mathematical explanation has already be done, I would like to add a personal experience. One of the kid I teached had another method: he would do `61 - 20 + 3`, as it is equal to `61 - (20 - 3)`. This is a way of having an easier substraction, and an addition which he was compfortable with. While this seems like the easiest way for me, that wasn't the "proper" way he was taught. He ended up frst of his promotion (college). The human brain is an incredible machinery; sometimes, what we think is the _best way_ is only applicable for ourselves. I believe you should support her idea.

Comment: The volume of responses you received in just one day should tell you just how close this is to the hearts of people that are heavily involved in mathematics and mathematical education: > Your daughter is probably not the next Einstein, but she is smart, and we all think this should be strongly encouraged. Please do not let (American) school inertia take it away from her.

Comment: @Alice Each person has different ways of thinking mathematically. What your daughter does is mathematically sound (as it is already shown in the answers) and definitely brilliant. Try not to let her get discouraged or forced to learn to do mathematics in the One and Only way her school teaches. It is important one to "understand" mathematical operations intuitively, not just learn to do them mechanically. Getting forced to adopt a way to do them against their intuition is exactly how a child gets to eventually hate mathematics. Please do not let her teachers destroy her mathematical thinking!

Comment: This works,but is difficult to extend to more than 2 digits.  The conditional reversing that is needed based on which operand has the higher digit in that place along with the required tracking of whether you are adding or subtracting into the next place can cause things to get lost pretty easily.  The advantage of the traditional method is that extending it to more places is simple and straightforward.

Comment: This is how my father taught me to subtract sums at a similar age. Apparently it's how he was taught during the '70s. There was a similar trick for multiplication and division fractions/decimals.

Comment: As a comment and protest about our education system I'd say that I think it's a terrible thing for a teacher to mark this down even if that's how it's often done. We supposedly want our kids to learn how to think creatively, but then penalize them when they do exactly that. What sort of message is that going to convey? If the method is valid, it should be accepted and encouraged, with EXTRA points for using novel thinking, not fewer points. If the teacher is not good enough to be able to figure out the validity of the method, the teacher should be fired and replaced/we need more good teachers.

Comment: Just more evidence of the bad state of our education system, as if the recent gun protests did not show us the importance of educating citizens with strong democratic skills for life in a democracy. We just don't teach people to THINK. Sorry about the ranting but I've got a serious bone with this.

Comment: There is usually more than one way to do lots of things. This is a great example. Trouble is, in schools, time rarely allows one to teach more than one way to a class of, sat, 30 (if you're lucky) children. So, one method is usually chosen, and stuck to. It's not a good premise, but a practical one. Sadly, it may leave several class members in the cold, who would have understood another method quicker. Insist that in reality, the correct answer has far more weight than the method used to get it.Good teachers will appreciate this - poor ones not. It's a bit like the method used for dart scores.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Yeah. OTOH it would not necessarily be good if teachers just gave any alternative approaches full, or even extra points. My teachers actually often did this (I was always a rebel and did everything differently), but often my methods were really not as efficient as the standard ones. The trick is to encourage thinking, but always _constructively remark_ when and why the established method is better.

Comment: I did it this way, too, at that age. Does that mean I'm gifted?

Comment: @leftaroundabout : Well yeah, if they do the addition problem by saying 25+15 is 25+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 and then counting by 1s, 26, 27, 28, 29, ... up to 40, then sure, that might not deserve a full mark. But at least you get the general idea of what I'm trying to drive at with this. If the method is comparable to the regular one (as in the case here) then you get a good mark, at least a full if not more depending on how deep an _understanding_ it shows. On the other hand though if they do do that +1+1+1... stuff then I suppose while it shouldn't get a full mark due to (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) inefficiency, it should get at least a comment that you understand the Peano definition of addition of natural numbers :) Which is something that could be built off of later, because you can actually use that to make a _proof_ of, say, the commutative law. Though then again nobody would likely know what they got on some exam long ago, just having some fun...

Comment: 61 - 17: She's adding the +1 to -7 getting a -6, then adding the -10 to the 60 leaving 50. 50 - 6 = 44
It works with 67-11, because +7 - 1 = +6, 60 - 10 = 50, therefore 56.

Comment: When I was a kid I solved assignments like "alice goes to the store 3 times and buys 6 apples each time" with 6x3=18 and got it marked wrong because it should be 3x6. Mathematics often dont allow intuitive solutions that the student can't prove, but that's something that can thouroughly destroy any fun your kid has. Please don't make her use only proven ways. Help her prove her ways (later). For now, by all means, allow this.

Comment: I spent a ridiculously long time thinking she was subtracting the 7-1 from the 17, and couldn't work out what the heck was going on.

Comment: Can we get rid of the clickbaity title?

Comment: Congratulations, your daughter has discovered the _integers_ $\mathbb Z$ – and you have earned a gold badge!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: I know your fandom to HNQ has no limits, but what's the point of unprotecting the question?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Because the deleted answer (essentially saying "we love you so much") looked like an isolated case to me. I do not see any need for protection.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: Have you noticed the *several* repeating answers by newcomers that were practically the same? Some received a couple of votes, some also garnered downvotes. Do you think we need more of these? Do you think with 18 answers people will actually spend time reading all of them before posting their own? (And for what it's worth, do you think that it's my first rodeo? Protecting a question over one deleted non-answer? ;-P)

Comment: @AsafKaragila OK, fine... I didn't see them.

Comment: Isn't that how everybody counts? O_o (I'm from eastern europe)

Comment: @Rodrigo A. Pérez no need point out "American" there.  Even if it seems to be a trait, it serves no purpose except to be rude, violating Be Nice.

Comment: Just tell your daughter that I'm impressed. I mean I'm impressed with her. I'm not impressed with her teacher who can't understand her method. And she has discovered a secret that bad teachers wouldn't want her to ever know: The fact that people can figure out things for themselves.

Comment: Don't want to break the party here but many comments praising your child's mind to the skies are actually doing the same mistake as the teacher: draw some superficial conclusion instead of seriously trying to understand her way of thinking. I agree with @SteveSmith : only if she can apply the rule (i.e. commutative and associative law) in other, versatile examples, too, one can be sure there is no coincidence (aka "lucky misunderstanding") involved.

Comment: @Nathan That's the way I do it, though seeing it written was a little bit confusing.

Comment: Many inexperienced or bad teachers feel threatened if a pupil does things differently than taught, because they feel that the pupil challenges their intelligence.This is a real problem for pupils that are a bit more intelligent or creative than the average.

Comment: @Dr Doolittle Apologies for buggering you, but could you please elaborate your answer? Despite being very happy about all the praises in the answers given, I admit that I never taught of my daughter as mathematically gifted. She always was slower than my other children at grasping mathematical concepts and hence my question in this forum. I was convinced that she was just lucky to be honest for having found a way that works. Maybe you are right... As a reply to Steve, when the minuend is larger than the subtrahend, she does the normal way: 67 - 11=> 7 - 1=6, 60 - 10= 50 => 6 + 50 = 56

Comment: Can't do diagnosis in this way (remote and indirect). (Why is there no teaching stackexchange site?) Good approaches would be: **1.** Ask her why she does it this way. From the answer one *could* gain insight into her thinking, but not necessarily. **2.** How does she solve 358-179?  **3.** It has been said before that there are always many possibilities. I believe thorough understanding comes only from being proficient in more than just one of them, i.e. it's probably a good exercise to practice the teacher's way even if your child doesn't prefer to use it afterwards.

Comment: I'm unpleasantly surprised your daughter's teacher can't comprehend this canny method.

Answer (score 291):

So she is doing 
\begin{align*}
61-17=(60+1)-(10+7)&=(60-10)-(7-1)\\
 & = 50-6\\
& =44
\end{align*}
She manage to have positive results on each power of ten group up to a multiplication by $\pm 1$ and sums at the end the pieces ; this is kind of smart :)

Conclusion : If she is comfortable with this system, let her do...

Comment: To explain it to the teacher: She copes with tens and ones separately and then puts it together. I named this method for myself: I look and I see.

Comment: @Thinkeye: It might help to recast the ordinary approach in the same terms: borrowing "pulls it apart" first, and *then* copes with the tens and ones separately. See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2669298/14972) for a slightly more general point of view.

Comment: I think it's easier to show how it can generalize better, or at least be more of a disciplined method, if you show it as (60-10) + (1-7) = 50-6. Then it's always top digit minus bottom digit, add up the results (noting negatives). this is of course a matter of opinion/preference, and in the end the only difference in in how you are thinking about the same operations.

Comment: The possible drawback would be that it becomes impossible while working with larger numbers, but it's not true: I tried 121-77 and 5003-7 (see following answer) and this technique also works, so only one advise: let your daughter keep her way of doing it (there's no mistake in being smart :-) ).

Comment: Where it would get complicated is a case like 287 - 193 because she is tracking sign by remembering which pairs were reversed.  For this you'd get (200-100) - (90-80) + (7-3) = 100 - 10 + 4 = 94.  The more digits you add, the more +/- you have to remember.  Doing it on paper that way, however, is really a nice simplification.

Comment: In the UK, we know this as partitioning. But she's very intelligent to come up with this by herself.

Comment: This is the same as normal column subtraction, just allowing for negatives instead of borrowing. $x-(7-1)$ is the same thing as $x+(1-7)$ afterall.

Comment: You might want to add a couple additional steps. If you apply the distribution of the negative sign, then group things in parentheses, and *then* negate the last pair (which flips the order of subtraction), it may be a little clearer to a person who doesn't use math very often.

Answer (score 180):

Your daughter is probably creating cognitive dissonance in her teacher because of the $7−1$ part.  "Doesn't she know she is supposed to subtract the $7$ from the $1$, and so then has to do a borrow, not the other way around?" the teacher is probably thinking.

But this is actually a very common way of doing things!
**Quick: What is $5003 - 7$?** If you are like me, your mind went right to **"whatever $5000 - 4$ is"**, that is $5000 - (7-3)$

To expand upon Netchaiev's answer, using Uppercase letters for numbers $>= 10$ and lowercase for numbers $< 10$:

$$(A+b)-(C+d) = A+b-C-d = (A-C)+(b-d)$$

If $b>d$, this works out easy without borrowing.  But if you have to borrow, then you do your daughter's (easier!) solution:

$$(A-C)-(d-b)$$

So it's actually a neat trick:  If you don't have to borrow, you use the normal method, but if you have to borrow, you use your daughter's method.

This method can be extended to subtracting numbers with three or more digits!  But then the bookkeeping could be troublesome.  Consider:

$$523-147 = (500-100) - (47-23), \space check!$$

But this could cause trouble, and you might want to see if this still works OK in your daughter's head:

$$517-161 = (500-100)-(61-17) = (500-100) - ( (60-10) - (7-1) ) = 400-44$$

Comment: @Ev.Kounis thanks for pointing it out. I just corrected it.

Comment: Thinking 61 = 50+11 _IS_ borrowing!  No matter how gifted an eight-year-old is, an _adult_ who can’t understand that should not be teaching math!

Comment: Using the daughters method I would rewrite your last example as (507-101) - (60 - 10), instead of what you did. Not that much harder as the other examples.

Comment: @WGroleau unfortunately should and could are very, very different things.

Comment: @WGroleau - Or be working at a cash register!

Comment: @fishinear  That's an interesting way of doing the subtraction, but honestly I don't if that as intuitive to others.  My last example is indeed not intuitive either and somewhat clumsy, which was the point I was trying to make - the gain in intuition and ease might be lost when you get to some cases with more digits.

Comment: @WGroleau  Not sure if the comment was directed at me, but maybe this is from me not being very precise or concise when I use the term "borrowing".  I meant to make a distinction between the (mentally) easier case of subtracting, say, 21 from 42, where you would subtract the "normal way" (adding 40-20 and 2-1), Versus the more difficult case such as subtracting 23 from 42 ("borrowing") in which case you'd use the daughters "algorithm"

Comment: Thanks and props to the kind soul who took my post and put it into proper fonts for arithmetic!  (unless that happens automatically?  it didn't look like that right after posting).
That was my first post to stackexchange.

Comment: No, I read the OP wrong.  61 = 50+11 is what she didn't do, and I read it backward.  But still, if the teacher passed algebra, he/she should still understand what the girl did AND recognize that it shows talent.

Comment: Claiming cognitive dissonance seems quite strong. In later stages of education, one will always lose marks if they solve a problem in a nonstandard way without explaining what they are doing and why it should work. The teacher might just be lazy and think its not their job to try to understand.

Answer (score 118):

A very useful generalization to decimal notation is to allow *arbitrary integers* for digits, rather than restrict digits to $0,1,\ldots,9$.

The semantics where each place corresponds to a multiple of a power of ten and then they are summed still applies.

In this notation, the calculation can be seen as first subtracting digitwise:

$$ \begin{matrix} & \fbox{6} & \fbox{1}
\\ -  & \fbox{1} & \fbox{7} 
\\\hline
& \fbox{5} & \fbox{-6}
\end{matrix}$$

Then, you can convert this to the usual form by normalizing the digits. In this case, you add ten to the one's place and subtract one from the ten's place to get $\fbox{4}\, \fbox{4} $. Note this operation is the same thing as borrowing, but it's being done at the end of the calculation rather than the beginning.

Arguably, the usual approach to subtraction is using the same idea, just rearranged differently: rather than normalize at the end as your daughter does, it *denormalizes* the number first, rewriting the subtraction as

$$ \begin{matrix} & \fbox{5} & \fbox{11}
\\ -  & \fbox{1} & \fbox{7} 
\\\hline
& \fbox{4} & \fbox{4}
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: This is a great answer! This idea and notation is exactly what was missing in the earlier (algebraic) answers. (I took the liberty of changing $\underline{6}$ etc. to $\fbox{6}$ as I found the underlines a bit confusing to read especially with the line just below, but feel free to revert if you don't like it.)

Comment: I would prefer to write the -6 as 6̅ - but that's because I am old enough to remember write log(0.2) = log(2) - 1 = 0.301 - 1 = 1̅.301 (where the 0.301 was looked up in log tables).
̅

Comment: This is exactly what I thought when I  read the question. Except the part about normalization. If you did 67 - 51, you could break it apart like 60-50 = 10 and 7 - 1 = 6, then add them together 10 + 6 = 16. Borrow doesn't make sense to her, but she is simply recognizing that subtraction is adding with negatives.

Comment: @Hurkyl well this just blew my mind

Comment: Yep. This is how I teach subtraction.

Comment: I find that this answer encapsulates the gist of the method. It is the method I use myself to mentally subtract.

Comment: Check out http://gdaymath.com/courses/exploding-dots/

Comment: It's crazy to read this now since i remember actually coming up with this way of doing subtractions in early school...

Answer (score 36):

I highly recommend that you read chapter 1 of Liping Ma's *Knowing and Teaching Elementary Mathematics – Teachers' Understanding of Fundamental Mathematics in China and the United States*, which is about how subtraction is taught in the US and China.  Here is a Chinese teacher's discussion of the problem $53-26$ from this chapter (p. 10):

[image: Liping Ma, p. 10]

Here is a Chinese teacher's discussion of how she teaches subtraction (p. 11-12):

> We start with the problems of a two-digit number minus a one-digit number, such as $34-6$.  I put the problem on the board and ask students to solve the problem on their own, either with bundles of sticks or other learning aids, or even with nothing, just thinking.  After a few minutes, they finish.  I have them report to the class what they did.  They might report a variety of ways.  One student might say "$34-6$, $4$ is not enough to subtract $6$.  But I can take of $4$ first, get $30$.  Then I still need to take $2$ off.  Because $6=4+2$.  I subtract $2$ from $30$ and get $28$.  So, my way is $34-6=34-4-2=30-2=28$."  Another student who worked with sticks might say, "When I saw that I did not have enough separate sticks, I broke one bundle.  I got $10$ sticks and I put $6$ of them away.  There were $4$ left.  I put the $4$ sticks with the original $4$ sticks together and got $8$.  I still have another two bundles of $10$s, putting the sticks left all together I had $28$."  Some students, usually fewer than the first two kinds, might report, "The two ways they used are fine, but I have another way to solve the problem.  We have learned how to compute $14-8$, $14-9$, why don't we use that knowledge.  So, in my mind I computed the problem in a simple way.  I regrouped $34$ into $20$ and $14$.  Then I subtracted $6$ from $14$ and got $8$.  Of course I did not forget the $20$, so I got $28$."  I put all the ways students reported on the board and label them with numbers, the first way, the second way, etc.  Then I invite students to compare: Which way do you think is the easiest?  Which way do you think is most reasonable?  Sometimes they don't agree with each other.  Sometimes they don't agree that the standard way I am to teach is the easiest way.  Especially for those who are not proficient and comfortable with problems of subtraction within $20$, such as $13-7$, $15-8$, etc., then tend to think that the standard way is more difficult.

There's more great stuff in this chapter, but this is a good sample.  You can read it for the rest.

Comment: Extremely pretty answer! Do you have any other book recommendation? I'm interested in this topic for pedagogical purposes.

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar Thanks! :) I don't know if directly relevant to this topic, but I really like [Hung-Hsi Wu's work](https://math.berkeley.edu/~wu/), especially [Understanding Numbers in Elementary School Mathematics](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821852604/ref=asc_df_08218526045182789?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&tag=shopzilla0d-20&ascsubtag=shopzilla_rev_479-20;15063164723474882445010090301008005&linkCode=df0&creative=395093&creativeASIN=0821852604)

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar I remember this book having some good tips as well: [How to Calculate Quickly](https://www.amazon.com/How-Calculate-Quickly-Arithmetic-Mathematics/dp/048620295X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1519981011&sr=8-1&keywords=how+to+calculate+quickly)

Answer (score 27):

I think what your daughter has discovered is "backwards" numbers.  She may have a different word for them, but I think of them as "backwards" because you subtract the numbers backwards.  A "forwards" number is 7 - 1 = 6, while a "backwards" number is 1 - 7 = "backwards" 6, because you do the subtraction backwards (7 - 1).  Adults, of course, call them "negative" numbers, but that's a silly name to a 3rd grader.  I think this because she intuitively knows that when you add a backwards number, you really subtract it, which is what she is doing.

Now, teachers know that few kids in 3rd grade can grasp negative numbers, so they teach borrowing instead.  Frankly, I suspect that a significant number of adults can't really grasp negative numbers.  But either way works mathematically.

As for your daughter and her teachers, I can think of two suggestions that may or may not help:

- Suggest that she calls them "negative" numbers and writes them as -6, and maybe her teachers can comprehend what she is doing.
- At her level, mathematics is simply counting and tricks (when we get into fractions, it is counting, measuring, and tricks, and so forth).  Try to get her to understand that the more tricks she knows, the easier it will be.  She found a great trick for subtraction, that of negative, or backwards, numbers.  There is another useful trick called borrowing.  Sometimes, one will be easier, sometimes the other will be easier.  Encourage her to learn both.

Good luck, and as others have said, if she can come up with this at 3rd grade, she has a bright future ahead of her.

Comment: I explain like that to her, she migh then be able to explain to her teacher what she is doing! :)

Comment: Go for it!  And if she uses different words, use her words instead of mine.  But do encourage her to learn borrowing as well (not "instead of"), and she'll have an easier time of it.  And if she can grasp that multiplying two backwards numbers produces a forward number, and that multiplying two half-backwards numbers produces a backwards number, she'll go far.

Comment: @GuySchalnat What are half-backwards numbers? O_o

Comment: @somebody: sqrt(-1)

Comment: @BenVoigt well technically if negatives are backwards complex would be sideways :P

Comment: I like "sideways",.  If "backwards" numbers are 180 degrees, "sideways" numbers are 90 degrees.  And "sideways" numbers are probably less intimidating sounding then "imaginary" numbers.  If you are driving down a road, and turn around to drive back for "backwards" numbers, it makes sense to turn on a cross street for "sideways" numbers.

Comment: At her level?  Mathematics is *always* simply counting and tricks.

Comment: @Yakk For fractions, measuring seems to make more sense then counting (especially if the kid helps out in the kitchen).  My mother would add that graph theory is map reading, but she went further into math than I did (I was really good at geometry proofs, and my high school geometry teacher also ran the school computer club, so he sort of guided my future career path).  But at the fundamental level, I sort of agree with you.  It is counting and tricks.

Answer (score 10):

Although the other answers are correct, I feel like they are overcomplicating how the calculation is done.

Due to how subtraction is taught in schools (at least in my school), it becomes really easy to subtract numbers away from a multiple of 10. For example, you learn really early on that 4 + 6 = 10, and therefore 10 - 6 = 4.

To better illustrate, imagine the question was 61 - 7.

- First, subtract a number so that the 61 becomes a multiple of 10. In this case, 1 (i.e. 61 - 1 = 60, which is a multiple of 10).
- Second, calculate how much of the second number (i.e. the 7) you have "left". This is what your daughter is calculating when she performs the 7 - 1 = 6 calculation.
- Finally, subtract 6 from 60, to give 54.

This is the way that I find most intuitive and is how I perform mental subtraction too. As stated by others, your daughter is very gifted to have derived this approach herself.

Comment: I am so grateful for all the help you have given to me. We used to live in the UK, but we are now in Switzerland. My daughter is 9 years old, she was born in November. I have read every single comment and I am taking on board your advices. Thank you!

Comment: This seems to begin with the second paragraph of [eachhisownchimera’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2667980/121411#2668319), but  (IMHO) your answer gives an explanation that is easier for a third-year arithmetic teacher to understand.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who is still a student, I can relate and explain.  This method is almost exactly the same as how I learned addition and subtraction.

It sounds like your daughter is taking apart the numbers and breaking them into smaller parts.  This is something I do too.  If you want to teach her how to do the work the "normal" way, don't.  This will only confuse her.  Also, tell her teachers that as long as she understands what she's doing and can explain it, they shouldn't mark her down.  Not everyone learns the same way and nobody should be told they're doing something wrong when they're not.  **She might not have the vocabulary to explain it all yet,** so be patient.  You'll see some amazingly complex things become very simple in her mind.

Now the math: Your daughter is looking at two different numbers, and thinking "How on earth does one go into the other?"  For her and millions of others, the simplest way is just to break it up.  Now, your daughter clearly is intelligent because she reasoned her way through this (yay future mathematician!!!) when others can't.  **If you take it down to the basics, she's adding negatives.**

She sees a 60 and 10 and takes the difference between them:  60-10=50

Now she sees a 7 and a 1 and takes the difference:  7-1=6

In her mind, she is just taking the difference, and knows that that number can be played with.  **She might not know what a negative is yet, but she understands them perfectly.**  For her that 6 is positive, but you can think about it like a negative 6.  i.e. -7+1=-6.  Because the 17 is being subtracted, you have the negative 7 from -17 compared to the positive 1 from +61.

Now she remembers that she flipped over (they became negatives, she just doesn't have the vocabulary) the 7 and the 1 to find 6.  Now, she knows that she needs to flip it back over so that the 7 is being subtracted from the 1.

To flip it back, she subtracts the 6 from the 50 (remember it's like a negative 6) to get 44.  In essence, this is all very simple with a good explanation.

61 - 17 = (60-10) + (-7+1) = (60-10) - (7-1) = 44

Answer (score 4):

It looks like she is taking $61 - 17 = 44$ and partially changing it to $17 - 61 = \!^-44$, then flipping the sign. She does $60 - 10 = 50$ in normal order, and then $7 - 1 = 6$ in reverse order. Doing another final subtraction flips the $6$ around to the correct sign again, so $50 - 6 = 44$.

Subtraction is actually just addition of negative numbers. If you have a Texas Instruments scientific calculator there is a different button for negative than subtraction. $61 + \!^-17 = 44$, just like $\!^-17 + 61 = 44$. Here is what she is really doing: $60 + \!^-10 = 50$ and $\!^-7 + 1 = \!^-6$. Add the two results together and you get $50 + \!^-6 = 44$.

What I remember from school is that not understanding that subtraction is really addition of negative numbers leads to a lot of problems down the road in more advanced math classes where you get problems like a $3(a -- b) = 4$. Just treat everything like addition and let negative signs stay with their numbers and cancel each other out and everything is less confusing!

Comment: Yes. She understands that the absolute of the difference between two numbers is independent on the order of operands (abs(1-7) = abs(7-1)); and then subtracts "the easy way around", i.e. does 7-1 instead of 1-7; and then makes up for the wrong sign by subtracting.

Comment: I hope she also gets shown (or will see quickly) that division is multiplication with the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

The most important aspect of this is not the mathematical method ... but the child i.e. your daughter.  Suppose she picked up a book and started reading from the last page and every word from right to left, but at the end (which is now the first page he he!) she could explain the story to you, then the objective of reading and the understanding of the story - has been achieved. Let your daughter find her own way in a very complicated world with many different paths and obstacles on the way.  There is almost invariably no 'right' way of doing or achieving anything in our world, merely a conventional way  ...

Comment: +1 for flexibility.  I remember my frustration in primary school at being forced to fill an entire sheet of paper doing a division problem that I could do in my head.

Comment: @WGroleau - I remember telling my son that it doesn't matter if you can do the homework problem in your head. Show the steps. The numbers are easy intentionally in order to make it easier for you to understand the steps. Learn the steps with 'easy' numbers and you'll be able to solve the harder numbers. Kids nowadays tend to not listen and he kept doing things in his head. In a few years when he got to where he couldn't do the problems in his head anymore he was struggling. After much frustration trying to figure out why he couldn't understand...

Comment: ...I realized that he didn't know how to do the basics. So we spent a few weeks relearning all the steps from previous grades and he suddenly was no longer struggling. The light bulb went off in his head and now he writes down the steps in all his classes.

Comment: I knew the basics.  They wanted us to not only show the steps most of learned, but to fill up the entire other half of the paper with steps to prove we had done the others correctly.  Basically, in fifth year, demanding an inefficient method for something I had learned in earlier years.  It’s not showing the steps that bugged me, it was a “method” that was two or more times longer than the one people have been using successfully for years.

Answer (score 2):

I think this method is awesome, it might even be easier than the classical method in some cases. Consider the following 'easy' subtraction, where the digit of the first number is bigger than the corresponding digit of the second number.

\begin{align}462-231&=(400+60+2)-(200+30+1)\\
&=(400-200)+(60-30)+(2-1)\\
&=200+30+1\\&=231\end{align}

Anyone would do this sum with little thinking. You would normally write it down without any steps inbetween. The method of your daughter extends this method to work with numbers that don't have this nice property.
\begin{align}431-262&=(400-200)+(30-60)+(1-2)\\
&=(400-200)-(60-30)-(2-1)\\
&=200-30-1\\
&=170-1\\
&=169
\end{align}
This could also be extended to larger numbers. To compare this to the usual method of borrowing tens I think that the regular method would be better if you have a pen and paper at hand and the numbers are relatively large, if you have no paper at hand this method might be easier.

Answer (score 2):

*(This is not meant to answer why it works formally, because this already been done, but rather a tentative to dwell in the girl's mind.)*

I was trying to put me in your daughter's shoes and wondering what could be the mental process going through her mind.

Since she always places the greater number as the subtrahend and the smaller one as the minuend when computing the subtractions it is not reasonable to think that she discovered the concept of a negative number.

Instead of that, it seems that she *intuitevely* understood the following two things:

1. A two-digit number is just the sum of the number formed by the "tens digit" followed by $0$ with the "unit digit". (For example, $47 = 40 + 7$.)
2. The way we count actually orders the numbers, that is, she can tell that a number $n_1$ comes first than another number $n_2$ by counting from $1$ to the latter, $n_2$. For example, if she wants to know if $3$ comes first than $7$, she (mentally) counts
   $$ 1, 2, \color{red} 3, 4, 5, 6, \color{red} 7 $$
   and so if she (mentally) said $3$ before $7$, then $3$ comes before $7$; or mathematically $3 < 7$. Also she understands that $0$ comes before every "counting number".

Furthermore she may have mastered the skill of computing subtractions with the non-negative integers less than $10$, namely $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, when the subtrahend is greater than the minuend. (This because she has only been taught doing this way and also one-digit subtractions are teached first).

So what she found is a pattern to find an easier and equivalent difference of two-digits numbers to a harder difference of two-digits numbers through her grasp of one-digit numbers subtraction.

This is enough to explain her mental process. Let's take your example: $61-17$. This difference of two-digit numbers is harder to do than the one she found using her method. Using her method she obtains an equivalent and easier difference that is $50-6$, a difference of a two-digit number and a one-digit number.

The thing is that her method always reduce the a difference of two-digit numbers to a difference or a sum of a two-digit number and an one-digit number.

But how does she knows when its a sum or a subtraction? For that she compares the unit digit of the subtrahend with the unit digit of the minuend. If the former is greater or equal the latter, then it is a sum, else it is a subtraction. Thus your daughter's evaluation of $61-17$ goes something like this in her mind:

> Since $1$ comes first than $7$, I subtract the result of $(7-1)$, namely $6$, from the number formed by the result of $(6-1)$, namely $5$, followed by a $0$, that makes $50$. Then I obtain $50 - 6$ which now I can evaluate. It is equal to $44$ and this is the result of $61-17$.

What is amazing, and you ***really*** should keep an eye on it, is that this method is applicable to the much more general scenario of integers subtraction, that is, the subtrahend and the minuend have an arbitrary number of digits, including a different number of each other, and the subtrahend may be less than the minuend. This means that your daughter can further develop her method to encompass all the possible cases of integers subtractions as the classes progress with the subtraction content. If this is the case then perhaps you are raising a future mathematician at home. :)

The following is what a systematized and more advanced version of her method could look like. Consider $147 - 76$.

> First we make the two numbers have the same quantity of digits: $147 - 076$.
>
> Now we respectively compare digit to digit and add to the total if the subtrahend digit is greater of equal to the minuend digit or subtract otherwise.
>
> Since $7 \ge 6$ we add $7-6 = 1$ to the total.
>
> Since $4 < 7$ we subtract the number formed by $7-4 = 3$ followed by **one** zero from the total.
>
> Since $1 \ge 0$ we add the number formed by $1-0 = 1$ followed by **two** zeros to the total.
>
> Therefore $147 - 76 = 100 - 30 + 1$. (Which is much more easier to compute.)

I have to say that it is very surprising that a third grader could find such a clever pattern. And she does this reasoning at an intuitive level, which only makes it more impressing!

May the gods of mathematics guide your daughter's path!

Comment: Pretty interesting answer, thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This will always work when subtracting two-digit numbers.
If we subtract two two-digit numbers in decimal notation $ab$ and $cd$ we get 
$$ab - cd$$
$$= 10*a + b - (10*c + d)$$
$$= (10*a - 10*c) - (d-b)$$

And that last line is exactly what your daughter is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your daughter is trying to use negative numbers, but not articulating it properly.  If you explain to her that it really is, she should be fine.  Emphasis on what I changed in your description:

Units of the *minuend* minus units of the *subtrahend*  $=1-6= -6$

Then tens of the minuend minus tens of the subtrahend $=60-10=50$

Finally she *adds, not subtracts* the first result *and* the second $=50 + (-6)=44$

Now, she can do her math is this fairly intuitive way, and articulate in a way that completely passes muster with the teachers.

Good for her for independently coming up with (90% of) the concept of negative numbers, and using those to simplify problems!

Comment: that should be 1-7=-6...

Comment: @Jesse Yes, after reading the answers and comments I understood as well and feel a little daft for not having thought of that... :) Another contributor pointed out that I can try to explain to her as backwards number. I am not sure if she will be able to understand the concept of negatives, as she is only 9. But its worth a try! Thanks again!

Comment: @Alice Hmm, you might be able to explain negatives by using real world equivalents? Like e.g. digging a hole and building it back up, or the distance to school relative to home (i.e. home is zero, negative is the direction away from school)?

Comment: @somebody That's a good idea! I explained to my 7 year old the concept of negatives using a thermometer, as we have - 11 degrees Celsius in Switzerland right now. He understood it quite easily. Children are amazing creatures.

Answer (score 0):

Your daughter is clever. She's breaking the numbers into smaller and easily subtractable numbers:
$$61-17= (50+11)-(10+7)$$

Rearranging the order:$$(50-10)+(11-7)=44$$

Comment: That's what she was taught in school, not what she is doing.

Answer (score 0):

What a coincidence, I used this exact same method when I was in school, but only mentally because it would be marked with a big red cross if it ever came on paper.

Its a brilliant little technique based on a little manipulation. It works like this: **61 - 17** is basically how much you have to add from 17 to get to 61. This can be done in two ways:

#### The method we use

We basically first compute how much you need to add to 17 (the smaller number) to get the unit digits to be the same: 4, since **17 + 4 = 21**. Then we find out the amount we now have to add, which is of course 40. Adding the two gives us 44. The first part of it is basically the carry: the amount you have to add to 17 to make the unit digit 1 is the amount you have to add to 7, the *minuend*, to make it 11, the smallest 2-digit number with a unit digit 1.

Consequently, the tens digit increases by one in the smaller number, and this is taken into account by subtracting the 1 from 6 or adding 1 to the 1 in 17.

#### The method your daughter uses

Imagine first adding 9 to your 61 and making it 70.
Then you add 3 to your 17 and make it 20.
Now (61 - 17) = (70 - 9) - (20 - 3) = (70 - 20) - (9 - 3)
Now it turns out that this (9-3) is the same as the difference between the minuend and the subtraend, (7-1). *This is **always** the case.*

And that is how your daughter does it.

Answer (score 0):

One really easy way to know that this will always work is to think of it as the addition of a positive and a negative number:

$61 + -17$

From there you can see what shes really doing:

$(61-1) + (-17+1)$

$60 + -16$

The equation is still balanced, therefore clearly still the same sum.
You can continue along this line of reasoning:

$(60-10) + (-16+10)$

$50 + -6$

$50-6=44$

Answer (score 0):

My way of explaining it:

\begin{align*}
61−17 &= (6 \cdot 10 + 1 \cdot 1) - (1 \cdot 10 + 7 \cdot 1) \\
      &= (6 - 1) \cdot 10 + (1-7) \cdot 1 \\
      &= (6 - 1) \cdot 10 - (7-1) \cdot 1 \\
      &= 5 \cdot 10 - 6 \cdot 1 \\
      &= 50 - 6 = 44 .
\end{align*}

---

On the one hand, you could generalise:
\begin{align*}
ABCD \ldots FG - abcd \ldots fg &= (A \cdot 10^\alpha + B \cdot 10^\beta + \ldots + F \cdot 10 + G) - (a \cdot 10^\alpha + b \cdot 10^\beta + \ldots + f \cdot 10 + g) \\
      &= (A - a) \cdot 10^\alpha + (B - b) \cdot 10^\beta + \ldots + (F - f) \cdot 10 + (G-g) ,
\end{align*}
and then rearrange to adjust signs.

On the other hand, you can be flexible :-) :
\begin{align*}
61−17 &= (50 + 5 + 6) - (10 + 6 + 1) = 50 - 10 + 5 + 6 - 6 - 1 = 40 + 5 - 1 = 44\\
61−17 &= (17+3+40+1) - 17 = 3 + 40 + 1 = 44 \\
61−17 &= (99-38) - (34-17) = 99-38-34+17 = 99-72+17 = 27+17=44 \\
\ldots&
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

People can't help what method they use in their head to solve a problem but they can try and find a way to get the right answer and as long as her method works, she might be unable to learn how to use the school's method in her head so I think it's better to leave her doing her own method. It works because 61 - 17 = (50 + 11) - 17 = 50 - (17 - 11) = 50 - 6 = 44. Good for her for figuring out her own method. I believe that I figured out on my own how to divide by 2 in decimal before I learned how to do long division.